# Pre-Calculus Vector Problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this question vector i represents a vector due east and vector j represents a vector 1 km due north.

> An aircraft flies (at a constant height) with a speed of $800$ km/h. It flies in a fixed direction from $A$ to $B$ for $30$ minutes, and then, in another fixed direction (diagonally), from $B$ to $C$ for $45$ minutes (which forms a triangle ^_^).
>
> (a) Find the distances $AB, BC$. 
>   The direction from $A$ to $B$ is due east. The direction from $B$ to $C$ is parallel to $24i + 7j$.
>
> (b) Use this information to find the angle theta that the aircraft turns through at $B$. Give your answer in degrees to the nearest tenth of a degree.
>
> (c) Find the Angle $ABC$. Hence find the direct distance from a to $C$.
>
> (d) Another aircraft flies directly from $A$ to $C$.
>
> (i) Show that vector $AC= 976 i = 168 j$.
>
> (ii) Find the angle $CAB$.
>
> (iii) When this aircraft is closest to $B$, how far is it from $A$?

Okay I think I got part A. $AB= 400$ km. $BC= 600$ km. 
I am sure that "the direction from $B$ to $C$ is parallel to $24i+7j$" is supposed to help me solve the rest, but I do not know what it means.

Could someone explain that to me and how to solve the rest?

Answer (score 1):

If the airplane flies from $A$ to $C$ for 30 minutes, then we can claim that the magnitude of the vector would be $400$ as the speed of the airplane is $800 ~ \rm km/h$.  Therefore, the vector would be $400\hat i$ as the the direction is due east.

It is a known fact that for a vector, $|\vec F|\hat F = \vec F $ where $\hat F $ is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec F$.  What is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{BC}$? Since $\vec {BC}$ is parallel to $24\hat i + 7 \hat j $, it is obvious that the unit vector is $\frac{24\hat i + 7 \hat j}{|24\hat i + 7 \hat j |} = \frac{24}{25}\hat i + \frac{7}{25}\hat j$. Also, the magnitude of $\vec {BC}$ is $800 \times \frac{3}{4} = 600$.

Now, using the relation $|\vec F| \hat F = \vec F$, we get $600 \times \left( \frac{24}{25} \hat i + \frac{7}{25}\hat j\right) = 576 \hat i + 168 \hat j $.

Also, note that $\vec {AC} = \vec{AB} + \vec{BC} = 400 \hat i + 576 \hat i + 168 \hat j = 976 \hat i  + 168 \hat j$.

Comment: Hello! If you are reading my answer, please note that I posted it a little late. The problem has already been solved, but I just wanted to add my two cents here.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the origin to be at $A$, point $B$ is $(400,0)$.  You are correct that the length of $BC$ is $600$.  $24i+7j$ is a vector from $(0,0)$ to $(24,7)$.  If you move the starting point to $B$, it is a vector from $(400,0)$ to $(424,7)$.  You need to scale up the vector $(24,7)$ to make the length $600$.  Can you find the length of $(24,7)$?  This should let you find the coordinates of $C$.  Draw a picture.  The turning angle is between the east ($x$) axis and $BC$.  You will need an inverse trig function to find the angle.

Under i, it is not true that $AC=976i=168j$.  The numbers are right, but what you have written says that three vectors are equal and they are not.

Comment: Oh for under i it supposed to Vector AC= 976 vector i+ 168 vector j

Comment: @Chris:  that is correct.  So point $C$ is $(976,168)$  You should be able to find the angles now.  Part iii is the hardest one.  You need to draw a line through $B$ perpendicular to $AC$ and calculate the length.  You have the slope of AC.  The slope of a perpendicular line is the negative reciprocal.

Comment: In addition @Ross Millikan, I am not sure what you mean by scale the vector (24,7), and how to find the length of (24,7). If I chose point B to be the starting point and "scale" the vector by (24,7), does that mean my new vector is (424,7)? If so, what am I supposed to do with that information?

Comment: @Chris: The length of $(24,7)$ is $\sqrt {24^2+7^2}=25$ so you need to multiply by $\frac {600}{25}=24$ to get a length of $600$.  This makes it $(576,168)$.  Adding that to $(400,0)$ gets the $(976,168)$ that are the coordinates of $C$

Comment: Okay, I understand the 576 value, but I still do not understand where the "168" came from.

Comment: @Chris:  It comes from multiplying $7$ by $24$.  It is the northward component of $BC$

Comment: Millikian Oh thanks! Okay then, by using the distance formula, line AC would be 990.3534723, Right? Or is there a way to get a better value? Then after having that value, I would utilize the law of cosines to get one angle, and then I could use law of sines to get the rest correct?

Comment: @Chris:  that is right.  You can also use $\arctan \frac {168}{976}$ for angle $A$